Controller parameters tuning without simulation
I am trying to find a way to tune the parameters of controllers with variable structure for power systems using Matlab and simulink. I would like to find a method where it is not needed to simulate the environment to tune the parameters. For now I use the minimization of the H2 or the H-infinity norm of the system. I am currently trying to tune the parameters of a simple PID controller for a second order plant (G(s) = 1 / (s^2 + 10s + 20)). The model is depicted below :
model
I have tried to use particle swarm optimization to minimize H2 or H-infinity norm of the transfer function :
T(s) = G(s) / (1 + C(s)G(s))
where G(s) is the transfer function of the plant and C(s) = Kp + Ki/s + Kd*s
The problem that I have is that the optimization return very large parameters (the order of magnitude of the gains is between 10^10 and 10^14) that lead to a non-ideal behvior.
For comparison this is the resulting behavior when optimizing with the norms:
norm
And this is the resulting behavior when optimizing with simulation :
simulation
The value of the H2 and H-infinity norms with the resulting parameters are very low while the resulting behavior is really oscillatory.
Thank you,

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What is the problem and show the code and how you did it
